# Spring Boot - Kotest Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotest

I'm trying to integrate Kotest with Spring Boot (I'm a beginner, so don't judge me harshly)

Here is my spring boot test class

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApiAutomationApplicationTests
```

Another Test class

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [A::class])
class Test1(
    @Autowired private val a: A
) : AnnotationSpec(){

    @Test
    fun test1(){
        a.printA()
    }

}
```

class A which has dependency class B

```
@Component
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [B::class])
class A(
    @Autowired private val b: B
) {
    fun printA(){
        println("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB")
        b.printB()
    }
}
```

and class B

```
@Component
class B {

    fun printB(){
        println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
    }
}
```

I've registered the SpringExtension globally

```
class ProjectConfig: AbstractProjectConfig() {
    override fun extensions() = listOf(
        SpringExtension
    )
}
```

When I try to run the test I getting following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@41b13f3d testClass = com.rezolve.api_automation.tests.Test1, locations = [], classes = [com.rezolve.api_automation.temp.A], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = [], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7cd4a4d7, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@2dd2e270, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@14fa92af, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0], contextLoader = org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at io.kotest.extensions.spring.SpringAutowireConstructorExtension.instantiate(SpringAutowireConstructorExtension.kt:27)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.InstantiateSpecKt.createAndInitializeSpec(instantiateSpec.kt:30)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.InstantiateSpecKt.instantiate(instantiateSpec.kt:11)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecRefKt.instance(SpecRef.kt:14)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor.createInstance-gIAlu-s(SpecExecutor.kt:132)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor.access$createInstance-gIAlu-s(SpecExecutor.kt:51)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$innerExecute$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:89)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$innerExecute$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$innerExecute$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.FinalizeSpecInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(FinalizeSpecInterceptor.kt:24)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.PrepareSpecInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(PrepareSpecInterceptor.kt:25)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.ApplyExtensionsInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(ApplyExtensionsInterceptor.kt:36)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.SpecFinishedInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(SpecFinishedInterceptor.kt:22)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.SpecStartedInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(SpecStartedInterceptor.kt:20)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.SpecRefExtensionInterceptor$intercept$inner$1.invokeSuspend(SpecRefExtensionInterceptor.kt:28)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.SpecRefExtensionInterceptor$intercept$inner$1.invoke(SpecRefExtensionInterceptor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.SpecRefExtensionInterceptor$intercept$inner$1.invoke(SpecRefExtensionInterceptor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.SpecRefExtensionInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(SpecRefExtensionInterceptor.kt:31)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.RequiresTagInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(RequiresTagInterceptor.kt:35)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.TagsInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(TagsInterceptor.kt:38)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.SystemPropertySpecFilterInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(SystemPropertySpecFilterInterceptor.kt:50)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.SpecFilterInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(SpecFilterInterceptor.kt:38)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.IgnoredSpecInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(IgnoredSpecInterceptor.kt:53)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.EnabledIfInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(EnabledIfInterceptor.kt:41)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.ref.RequiresPlatformInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(RequiresPlatformInterceptor.kt:32)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invokeSuspend(SpecExecutor.kt:94)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor$referenceInterceptors$3$1.invoke(SpecExecutor.kt)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor.referenceInterceptors(SpecExecutor.kt:95)
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.SpecExecutor.execute(SpecExecutor.kt:63)
    at io.kotest.engine.ConcurrentTestSuiteScheduler$schedule$8$1$2.invokeSuspend(ConcurrentTestSuiteScheduler.kt:73)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at io.kotest.common.RunBlockingKt.runBlocking(runBlocking.kt:3)
    at io.kotest.engine.TestEngineLauncher.launch(TestEngineLauncher.kt:221)
    at io.kotest.runner.junit.platform.KotestJunitPlatformTestEngine.execute(KotestJunitPlatformTestEngine.kt:78)
    at io.kotest.runner.junit.platform.KotestJunitPlatformTestEngine.execute(KotestJunitPlatformTestEngine.kt:50)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'a': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.rezolve.api_automation.temp.B' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:221)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:110)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:212)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119)
    ... 111 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.rezolve.api_automation.temp.B' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1824)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1383)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 128 more
```

Please help me to find the problem and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

A Spring Boot application is a Spring ApplicationContext, so when we use the @SpringBootTest it requires the ApplicationContext, and to get the main configuration, according to spring docs

> The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test
> until it finds a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication or
> @SpringBootConfiguration. As long as you structured your code in a
> sensible way, your main configuration is usually found.

You can solve configuration loading error by:

1. By placing your test class in same package as your main configuration
   If test class belongs to the same package as your main configuration Spring will automatically create the ApplicationContext.
2. You can give the main class of your spring application in SpringBoot Test annotation
   eg if App is your main class

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = [App::class])
class ApiAutomationApplicationTests
```

Resources: [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config)